# MYSQL: Select specific column value depending on condition

Tags: mysql

I have table with columns

```
id doctor_name charges_cash charges_cashless
1      1             300         600
2      2             200         400
```

Now I am trying to run this query:

```
SELECT ipd.patient_name, r.room_name, doctor.doctor_name,
CASE p.tpa_name
WHEN NULL
THEN i.charges_cash
ELSE i.charges_cashless
END AS 'charges'
FROM `daily_ward_entry` d, ipd_charges i, ipd_patient_entry ipd, room_charges r, 
patient_detail p, doctor
WHERE d.doctor_visit_name = i.doctor
AND r.id = d.room_name
AND d.patient_name = ipd.id
AND d.doctor_visit_name = doctor.id
```

I am getting the result for charges as 400 whereas p.tpa_name being null, I expect it to be 200,
I am out of any clue, what I am doing wrong here?

The result set is like this

```
patient_name  room_name doctor_name charges
Sapna Agrawal  MG-1      Dr. Dungri  400
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're missing the rest of the tables?

Comment: A guess would be that some of your tables have multiple rows that match and hence duplicate rows on your main table. But without knowing what the table structures are and some idea of test data it is pretty much impossible to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `IS` operator when comparing to `NULL`

```
CASE WHEN p.tpa_name IS NULL
     THEN i.charges_cash
     ELSE i.charges_cashless
END AS 'charges'
```